# Get the username in Forms authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication, windows-authentication

I'm using Forms authentication.

In Windows Authentication for get the user name of the PC i use: `User.Identity.Name`

I need this information also in Forms authentication but `User.Identity.Name` doesn't work.

How can I get the User.Identity.Name without using Windows authentication?

Answer (score 64):

To get the UserName of the authenticated user:

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
```

Comment: Are you sure you have the Forms Authentication setup correctly in the web.config file? What does this return 'this.Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated'

Comment: @Luca Romagnoli can you post your web.config file? or at least the authentication section and any authorization sections you have?

Comment: @Luca: An empty string (typically) means you are an unauthenticated entity.

Comment: I set ***AUTH cookie*** using `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(tbUserName.Text, False)` and I get ***Username value*** using `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`, `Page.User.Identity.Name`, and `Page.User.Identity.Ticket.Name` (for _AuthenticationType = Forms_)

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly how I do it, I think there might be something wrong with your setup?  For example, are you actually logged into the site while your debugging?  If not, you need to in order to get a value.

Answer (score 0):

It may depend on when in the lifecycle you are asking.

If you handle `BeginRequest()` then there will not yet be any authentication information. Whereas if you handle `EndRequest()` there will.